# JavaScript delay inside a function, without globals

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to wait for async operations inside a function without global variables?

I know, if I have a global I can delay like this:

```
var flag = 0; // global

function wait_for_convert() {
    if(!flag) {
        setTimeout(wait_for_convert, 50);
    }
    else {
        request.send(data);
    }
}
wait_for_convert();
```

But, if I have many async operations, It's very annoying to put all of these waits to global scope.

For example I need a function that returns data, from async requests, like this:

```
function append_resized(resized_images, name, file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");

        img.onload = function() {
            var dataurl = dataurl_resize(this);

            // WOULD BE NICE TO RETURN THIS RESULT
            // LIKE THIS: return {'blob': dataURLtoBlob(dataurl), 'filename': file.name};
            resized_images[name] = {'blob': dataURLtoBlob(dataurl), 'filename': file.name};
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            resized_images[name] = undefined;
        }
        img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Also may be there are libs to lock async request to sync, or something else?

Comment: Have a look at IcedCoffeeScript: http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callbacks, and actually I would suggest only this solution (how many flags can you have?):

```
function afterSomething() {
    request.send(data);
}
```

This callback can be passed to another function and triggered from there:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    // do something
    callback();
}

doSomething(afterSomething);
```

Doing this you can create chains of callbacks, existing in different scopes, and so on. This is how powerful functional programming is.

So according to your example you could do sth like this:

```
function onLoadCallback(name) { console.log(name); }

function append_resized(resized_images, name, file, onLoadCallback) {
    ...
    img.onload = function() {
        var dataurl = dataurl_resize(this);

        // WOULD BE NICE TO RETURN THIS RESULT
        // LIKE THIS: return {'blob': dataURLtoBlob(dataurl), 'filename': file.name};
        resized_images[name] = {'blob': dataURLtoBlob(dataurl), 'filename': file.name};

        onLoadCallback(name); // you can pass whatever you want and need of course
    };
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think I understand. 

For my function "append_resized", it means that I have to add "callback" function in parameters and this "callback" checks all resized_images[name] and if all is ok sends request.

(PS: this function resize a few images and all of this images are resized by async requests, and I have to wait while 1..20 images will be resized)

Comment: @kwild I have just edited my solution to show you the way how you can use callbacks in your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can try jQuery Deferreds, should fit in:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/